# Java Post request does not send file

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am trying to send out a post request containing a file as well. For some reason, my file doesn't get sent. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
**  public String postReceipt(String token, String FilePath) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException { 
    Log.i("postData receipt", FilePath);
    File image = new File(FilePath);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    Log.i("image name", image.getName());

    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();  
    multipartEntity.addPart("access_token", new StringBody(token));
    multipartEntity.addPart("receipt[image]", new FileBody(image));
    // multipartEntity.addPart("image", new FileBody(image)); -> 500

    multipartEntity.addPart("store[name]", new StringBody("Some Store"));        
    multipartEntity.addPart("store[street]", new StringBody("Backstr. 29")); 
    multipartEntity.addPart("store[zip]", new StringBody("12047"));        
    multipartEntity.addPart("store[city]", new StringBody("Hamburg")); 
    multipartEntity.addPart("store[country]", new StringBody("DE")); 

    httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
    String responseString = out.toString();
    Log.i("postData receipt", response.getStatusLine().toString());
    Log.i("postData receipt", responseString);
    return "DONE";
}
```

*** $data = array 
    ( 
        'access_token' => '248628ecd3342828e6', 
        'receipt[image]' => '@d:\a67ff68fb34113ac300af9dde46b8aec__2.jpg'
    );

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
$result = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);  
print_r($result); ***
```

**

Comment: How do you checking that file is sent on backend?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. I get a "bad" response from the API. FYI, I am sure the file exists on my side, I can see its name when I print it in the log.

Comment: First of all seeing name doesn't mean nothing - file may not exists. Does LogLat shoow you something errors?

Comment: I am certain the file exists. No errors that I can see..

Comment: ok, do you have an access to API or it documentation?

Comment: Btw: I was able to make request work with the following php code, so the fault must lie in my java code.

Comment: I am wondering about your args naming approach - do you really use $_FILES["receipt[image]"] on your backend ?

Comment: how about creating a local web server to accept this request and debug from there on

Comment: I was able to submit it with some PHP code. Please look above.